# Rabin-Karp method for string matching

Tags: algorithm, rabin-karp

Using the Rabin-Karp method for string matching, how many character-character matches does the method use?
Where:

```
source  = abcabcabcacd
pattern = bcac
```

Comment: 1.  Research the Rabin-Karp method. 2. Run through the method counting the number of character matches.  3. Return the result.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start from the algorithm itself. How does Rabin-Karp methods work. I will use **C#** code to illustration.
Having

```
  string target = "bcac";
  string source = "abcabcabcacd";
```

we compute hash for the `target`:

```
  int targetHash = RabinHash(target);
```

and then *efficiently* compute hashes for all substring of `target` length (here of substrings of length `4`):
`"abca"`, `"bcab"`, ... `"cacd"`. If `targetHash` *equals* to substring's hash we compare this substring and
`target` corresponding letters. For instance:

if `targetHash = 888` and for substrings we have, say,

```
  abca : 555 
  bcab : 345 
  cabc : 888 <- check this (failure due to hash collision)
  abca : 555 
  bcab : 345 
  cabc : 888 <- check this (failure due to hash collision) 
  abca : 555 
  bcac : 888 <- check this (success)
  cacd : 900
```

Here we have 3 episodes of character-character matching. Now we are ready to answer your question: the number
of character-character matching *depends* on hash function.

**Worst case:** we have nothing but hash collisions:

```
  int RabinHash(string value) => 1;
```

All **9** substrings should be character-character checked.

**Best case:** we have no hash collisions; say, we can implement a typical Rabin hash function as

```
  int RabinHash(string value) => value.Aggregate(0, (s, a) => s * 26 + a - 'a');
```

And we should check the only **1** actual matching:

```
  string target = "bcac";
  string source = "abcabcabcacd";

  // int RabinHash(string value) => 1;
  int RabinHash(string value) => value.Aggregate(0, (s, a) => s * 26 + a - 'a');

  int targetHash = RabinHash(target);

  var report = Enumerable
    .Range(0, source.Length - target.Length + 1)
    .Select(i => source.Substring(i, target.Length))
    .Select(chunk => new { 
      chunk,
      hash = RabinHash(chunk)
    })
    .Select(item => $"{item.chunk} : {item.hash,5} {(item.hash == targetHash ? "<- check it" : "")}");

  Console.Write(report);
```

**Outcome:**

```
  abca :   728 
  bcab : 18929 
  cabc : 35180 
  abca :   728 
  bcab : 18929 
  cabc : 35180 
  abca :   728 
  bcac : 18930 <- check it
  cacd : 35207
```

**Final answer:** Depending on hash function, we have to check from `1` up to `9` times.